# Solution to test low phone storage?

Tags: android, android-internal-storage

I am looking for a solution to test low phone storage for some other app on Android. One solution is to create an application which would fill up the whole memory but that doesn't seem to be working. Is there any other solution someone can suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Two options I could think of:

1. Setup an AVD with a minimum amount of available memory.
2. Decouple physical state of the device and your app using a method you can control. Set-up a proxy method (you might call it something like `availableStorageSize()`) and make sure it's the only way for your app to ever learn about free storage space. That way you'll have more power to simulate scenarios like those.

---

**Edit**: As per the comments thread of this answer, you're telling us that you're using `getAvailableBytes()` to determine whether or not there's enough memory available and that "if getAvailableBytes returns low memory [you] don't download it".

With emulator and rooting out of the question, all that I think you could still do is to wrap that `getAvailableBytes()` inside a method of your own. Looking something like:

```
private fun deviceHasEnoughStorage(size: Long): Boolean {
    return size < getAvailableBytes()
}
```

Then, to test low memory scenario, alter this method to always return `false`:

```
private fun deviceHasEnoughStorage(size: Long): Boolean {
    return false // Simulate low storage state.
}
```

Next, make sure not to use `getAvailableBytes()` anywhere ever again in your project, otherwise there might be some inconsistencies here and there.

> Disclaimer: This is more of a last resort rather than an ideal solution. Use the emulator whenever possible to test device-related scenarios like this.

Comment: Is it possible on real device without rooting?

Comment: If you're going with `2` then sure. Otherwise, I'm afraid no.

Comment: @Hadi Satrio #2 is good for testing code like `if (lowMemory()) ....` What about code with unexpected Exceptons (Runtime, OutOfMemory and similar)

Comment: @k3b, well then make sure you check for low memory before executing code that might throw exceptions related to low memory. I get that it might not sound practical but that's the only thing I could think of given that both emulator and rooting are out of the question.

Comment: I didn't quite get it, can you please explain with some example?

Comment: Sure, but first can you tell me the way your app is using to determine whether or not a device is low in storage?

Comment: actually I am downloading some assets from server on app launch. So if `getAvailableBytes` returns low memory I don't download it.